# Haskell: input a list and output its minimum value

Tags: list, haskell, io

I am learning Haskell and I want to take as input a list, and output the minimum value using the function minimum.

```
    module Main where

    main = do putStrLn "Enter list"
              list <- readLn
              putStr "minimum list = "
              print (minimum list)
```

However I get some errors:

```
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

and:

```
    No instance for (Ord a0) arising from a use of `minimum'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

I have been reading up on Haskell typeclasses and type signatures from various sources around the web, but so far nothing has illuminated the course of action most amenable to the aforementioned quandary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your type really *is* ambiguous: The code could work for *any* type that implements `Ord` and `Show`, and the compiler doesn't know which one to choose.  To fix this, add a type annotation somewhere to tell it which type you want it to use. E.g. for a list of `Integer`s:

```
module Main where

main = do putStrLn "Enter list"
          list <- readLn
          putStr "minimum list = "
          print (minimum list :: Integer)
```

Comment: I tried your fix but now I am running into something else. When I run the code and enter a list of integers, say [2,3,4], I get: `*** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)`

Comment: @user66309 I had a stupid error in my first version of the post, you may have seen that. If so, try `Integer` instead of `[Integer]`.